# C: How to check if data from file is a number

Tags: c

As part of a university project I have to build a program which should receive an input file with initial parameters.

In process of making sure the input file is valid -Ii have to check that it contains only numbers (i.e. 7, -3.25, +0.24, 212 etc.), no text or other symbols.

How can I do that while reading data from file?

Should I  use the `isdigit()` function? But that will be problematic considering that '-', '+' and '.' are ok, too.

Would really appreciate if you could guide me in the right direction.

Comment: Look into a function called strtod. This should provide you the functionality that your require. You will need some additional logic to separate each string.

Comment: Check one character at a time; `-`, `+`, and `.` are only ok in *some* positions.

Answer (score 1):

As you said, using the function isDigit() wouldn't be the best option because the input can have symbols like '+', '-' or '.'.
So as a suggestion, using regex.h you could use the following regular expression to take numbers only with that format:

/^[+-]?\d+.?\d+$/

You can copy that on here: https://www.regextester.com/ to understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the GNU C regular expression library `regex.h`, found [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Regular-Expressions.html).

However, if this is an introductory programming class, then it is possible that your professor simply wants you to get comfortable using a series of `if-else` statements (in combination with the `isdigit()` function) to determine whether or not each input is valid.

Comment: [Regular Expressions: Now You Have Two Problems](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)